# How to specify which JSON library for AFNetwork

Tags: ios, afnetworking

For the [AFNetwork](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) , it provides ability to choose several JSON open source library, like

> AFNetworking uses NSJSONSerialization if it is available. If your app targets a platform where this class is not available you can include one of the following JSON libraries to your project for AFNetworking to automatically detect and use.

- JSONKit
- SBJson
- YAJL
- NextiveJson

My question is how to speicify the JSON library with code or configuration instead of automatical way.

Answer (score 0):

For using the native iOS JSON API, just code like this in the .pch file

## define _AFNETWORKING_PREFER_NSJSONSERIALIZATION_ 1